# mobile version doesn't load after setting conditional viewport meta tag

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, viewport, meta-tags

I'm now working on a website which I used on it a conditional viewport meta tag:

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=1100, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<script>
        deviceWidth = window.innerWidth;
        var viewport = document.getElementById('viewport');
        if(deviceWidth <= 480) viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0');
</script>
```

It works fine in all devices its `width > 480px`, but for the devices with `width < 480px` the mobile version loads with issues in the style or don't load at all.

So how to solve this issue ?

Comment: This issue didn't been solved yet, please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: What is the difference between them ? Thanks.

Comment: Essentially doing the same thing but with less work?